# How to make Conky text semitransparent?

Tags: compiz, conky, xorg

Okay, before you ask me to *RTFM*, I'll show you a screenshot, and describe my situation:

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

This is what I want to get. The screenshot above shows (semitransparent) Conky, but the transparency is provided by adding an opacity filter for Conky in *ccsm*. Needless to say, that only works when the window is controlled by the *WM*, ie. when Conky is in **normal** mode (and not **desktop** or **override**). This is kinda okay, but if you click the "Show/Hide All Windows" button, Conky gets hidden as well (which ideally, should not happen.

### Conky Configuration File

```
alignment top_right
background yes
use_xft yes
xftalpha 0.1
border_margin 5
border_width 5
default_color white     # grey 5f5f5f 3F3F3F
double_buffer yes
draw_borders no
draw_outline no
draw_shades no
gap_x 30
gap_y 60
maximum_width 240
minimum_size 175
no_buffers yes
override_utf8_locale yes
own_window yes
own_window_title conky
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_type override    ## normal /override /desktop
text_buffer_size 200
total_run_times 0
update_interval 1
uppercase no
xftfont Ubuntu Beta:size=8

#               fonts
#   Blue Highway
#   Zegoe Light - U
#   Zekton
#   Calibri
#   Engebrechtre
#   Opeln2001
#       Aller Display

TEXT
${font Aller:pixelsize=55}${alignc}${time %H:%M}${font}

${font Aller:pixelsize=11}${alignc}${time  %B %d, %Y}
${alignc}${time %A}${font}

#${voffset 10}${alignc}${font StyleBats:size=8}A${font} CPU1: ${cpubar cpu1 9,80}
#${alignc}${font StyleBats:size=8}A${font} CPU2: ${cpubar cpu2 9,80}
#${alignc}${font StyleBats:size=8}g${font} RAM:  ${offset 1}${membar 9, 80}
#${font Webdings:size=10}~$ ${battery_bar}
```

### ...and more

I've used every possible combination of argb settings and stuff, but nothing works. I really want it to be:

1. Semitransparent
2. "Sticky", so that it isn't minimized when you use C-D or "Hide All Windows"

Comment: We don't give an RTFM or LMGTFY at Ask Ubuntu. :)

Comment: Sid: ;). On a side note, when I was trying to configure compiz to enable the fake-transparency, I accidentally made all windows 100% transparent. Fixing that was fun :)

Answer (score 4):

To enable compositing, i.e., **true transparency** not just pseudo-transparency, you have to enable ARGB:

```
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_class conky-semi
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 128
```

If you want a semi-transparent black background, just set `own_window_transparent no`

To control the transparency level, play with `own_window_argb_value`, ranging from 0 to 255.

Source: http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/13231/solved-compositing-and-conky-wierdness/

Comment: i love how `own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager` lets you create a window __like__ desktop but without all the glitchiness

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
own_window yes
own_window_title conky
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
```

Then go to the compiz setting (CCSM), enable "opacity, brightness and whatever", click on the leftmost "opacity" tab. Let <kbd>Alt</kbd> Button4 and <kbd>Alt</kbd> Button5 control the opacity/transparency setting.

After that just mouse-over conky and let the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button rock & roll.

Comment: This worked for me with the additional step of going into CompizConfig Settings Manager under General Options and unchecking "Hide Skip Taskbar Windows". This keeps conky from disappearing off the desktop.

Comment: One more thing: to get rid of the shadows for conky, I had to put `!name=Conky` in "Shadow windows" of "Window Decoration" in CompizConfig Settings Manager.